# Is this going to cause problems on the stack?

Tags: c, optimization, stack-overflow

I have a function that writes a bitmap string to a browser, which then prints it on screen. Currently this works by generating the correct values for each pixel individually and using the `write(int fd, char *Buff, int NumBytes)` function three times for every pixel, e.g.:

```
for (i = 0; i < IMAGE_HEIGHT; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < IMAGE_WIDTH; ++j)
    {
        blue = blue();
        green = green();            
        red = red();

        write(soc, &blue, 1);
        write(soc, &green, 1);
        write(soc, &red, 1);
    }
}
```

I was wanting to optimize the code and figured that calling the write() function so many times is surely costing me something. So, the idea was to store all the values in a character array and then call the write function once:

```
write (soc, image_array, sizeof(image_array));
```

but am I going to have problems with the huge arrays (100's of thousands/millions of elements)? Would just allocating to the heap solve this? I just wanted to make sure I'm not doing anything stupid.

Comment: Your image isn't in a char array to begin with?

Comment: @Pubby: No, I create it based on some input.

Comment: Memory mapped IO is another way to manipulate files as though they were in memory, if your implementation supports it. This is particularly good for large memory/file objects like images. Note advantages and disadvantages: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/BrainDump/Using-mmap-for-Advanced-File-IO/ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the multiple writes will hurt you.

Rather than write each byte individually or allocate the entire thing, I suggest writing to a small buffer (perhaps a few KB) and writing that every time it fills up. That should give you a good performance gain for small memory cost.

Comment: I'll try a few, but what do you think would be a good/optimal buffer size?

Comment: It depends on many things, and you don't need "optimal". a 1KB buffer is small even in the embedded world but will cut down your number of system calls by 3 orders of magnitude. Should be a good gain.

Comment: Hmmm, not much luck with this. It seems to load at approximately the same speed as just calling the write() function a bunch of times, accept instead of loading slowly and smoothly, it loads in bursts with pauses in between :D I tried buffer sizes from ~500 - 13,000. I guess the assigning to the char array is comparable to calling write in terms of time...

Comment: There's always something slowing you down. Presumably you have something else slowing you down more.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in a typical case using dynamic allocation will cure (or at least relieve) the problem. On a typical system (e.g., Windows or Linux) the stack is limited to a few megabytes or so (somewhat variable, can be adjusted as link time, at least on Windows).

The space you have available on the free store tends to be limited primarily by available address space (or, in the case of a single large allocation, contiguous address space). Allocating up to a couple of gigabytes is fairly routine. On a 64-bit system, even larger allocations become fairly reasonable (in this case, typically limited primarily by available RAM, and how much slow-down you're willing to accept from using virtual memory).

Comment: Then, I guess, would the slow down from the use of virtual memory be less than the slow down from millions of function calls? Can you say, or am I just going to have to test it myself? :S

Comment: The answer is always "try it and profile it". But also see my suggestion.